# MySQL Table Query Unusually Slow (Using Matlab's Connector/J)

Tags: mysql, matlab

**EDIT:** Thank you everyone for your comments.  I have tried most of your suggestions but they did not help.  I need to add that I am running this query through Matlab using Connector/J 5.1.26 (Sorry for not mentioning this earlier).  In the end, I think this is the source of the increase in execution time since when I run the query "directly" it takes 0.2 seconds.  However, I have never come across such a huge performance hit using Connector/J.  Given this new information, do you have any suggestions?  I apologize for not disclosing this earlier, but again, I've never experienced performance impact with Connector/J.

---

I have the following table in mySQL (`CREATE` code taken from HeidiSQL):

```
CREATE TABLE `data` (
    `PRIMARY` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `ID` VARCHAR(5) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `DATE` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `PRICE` DECIMAL(14,4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `QUANT` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `TIME` TIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    INDEX `DATE` (`DATE`),
    INDEX `ID` (`SYMBOL`),
    INDEX `PRICE` (`PRICE`),
    INDEX `QUANT` (`SIZE`),
    INDEX `TIME` (`TIME`),
    PRIMARY KEY (`PRIMARY`)
)
```

It is populated with approximately 360,000 rows of data.

The following query takes over 10 seconds to execute:

```
Select ID, DATE, PRICE, QUANT, TIME FROM database.data WHERE DATE 
>= "2007-01-01" AND DATE <= "2010-12-31" ORDER BY ID, DATE, TIME ASC;
```

I have other tables with millions of rows in which a similar query would take a fraction of a second.  I can't figure out what might be causing this one to be so slow.  Any ideas/tips?

EXPLAIN:

```
id = 1
select_type = SIMPLE
table = data
type = ALL
possible_keys = DATE
key = (NULL)
key_len = (NULL)
ref = (NULL)
rows = 361161
Extra = Using where; Using filesort
```

Comment: Please don't call your table "data", or your database "database".  It tells the reader absolutely nothing about what is inside.  It's like if you had a box with stuff in it and you labeled it "matter".  Use a descriptive name.

Comment: Got any EXPLAIN output?

Comment: Any chance that all the reserved words are causing an issue here?  Maybe, get some backticks around `DATE` and `TIME` in the query.

Comment: @ Andy: I renamed the database for the question, along with some of the fields.  The names are much more intuitive in reality.

Comment: @Buggabill: I have tried that as well

Comment: Please post the EXPLAIN output

Comment: How many rows are returned? And does anything change if you omit the `ORDER BY`?

Comment: can you show me an EXPLAIN off the slow query?

Comment: indeed the query needs a FULL TABLE SCAN, Whats your storage engine? like Gordon Linoff sad the problem is in in asking a too wide range and sorting results. how many records does the query return? And did you tryed the query off Gordon Linoff?

Comment: @ Raymond: I edited my question (at the top).  I now know the problem stems from elsewhere, but I still don't know how to fix it...

Comment: @Mr.Kinn and if you select an smaller date range did you tryed that also?

Comment: Yes, it's faster, but still much much slower than running the query directly.  I've never had problems with Connector/J before and just ran a number of older queries (on other, but larger, tables) and they all executed very quickly...

Answer (score 3):

You are asking for a wide range of data.  The time is probably being spent sorting the results.

Is a query on a smaller date range faster?  For instance,

```
WHERE DATE >= '2007-01-01' AND DATE < '2007-02-01'
```

One possibility is that the optimizer may be using the index on `id` for the sort and doing a full table scan to filter out the date range.  Using indexes for sorts is often suboptimal.  You might try the query as:

```
select t.*
from (Select ID, DATE, PRICE, QUANT, TIME
      FROM database.data
      WHERE DATE >= "2007-01-01" AND DATE <= "2010-12-31"
     ) t
ORDER BY ID, DATE, TIME ASC;
```

I think this will force the optimizer to use the `date` index for the selection and then sort using file sort -- but there is the cost of a derived table. If you do not have a large result set, this might significantly improve performance.

Comment: Running this actually makes the query run slightly longer (both in Matlab and directly)

Comment: @Mr.Kinn . . . How many rows are being returned?  How fast is it on a smaller date range?

Comment: The query (run through Matlab) returns 239,245 rows and takes ~10 seconds.  The same exact query run through HeidiSQL takes 0.20 seconds.  With a one-year range the query takes 1.3 seconds (in Matlab) and returns 61,086 rows.  This second query takes 0.14 seconds in HeidiSQL.

Comment: @Mr.Kinn . . . The problem could be the amount of time to load the rows into Matlab. You could test this by running the query:  `select count(*) from (<current query>) t`.  Or, running the query without the `order by` to see if that affects performance.

Comment: Thanks for your help and insight, Gordon. Running the `select count(*)` statement takes only 0.30 seconds.  So I guess the problem is loading the rows into Matlab as you say.  Do you have any idea how I might be able to speed this up?  Unfortunately I need to run similar queries consecutively and that really adds up...

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already tried to `OPTIMIZE TABLE` and got no results.

You can either try to use a covering index (at the expense of more disk space, and a slight slowing down on `UPDATE`s) by replacing the existing date index with

```
CREATE INDEX data_date_ndx ON data (DATE, TIME, PRICE, QUANT, ID);
```

and/or you can try and create an empty table `data2` with the same schema. Then just `SELECT` all the contents of `data` table into `data2` and run the same query against the new table. It could be that the `data` table needed to be compacted more than `OPTIMIZE` could - maybe at the filesystem level.

Also, check out the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT...` for that query.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with mysql but mssql so maybe:

what about to provide index which fully covers all fields in your `select` query.

Yes, it will duplicates data but we can move to next point of issue discussion.